# Firebase Auth Token for Firebase Admin SDK with a Service Account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, authorization, access-token, firebase-admin

I built Firebase API which uses the following to authorize Firebase ID tokens which are created by Firebase when a user signs into the Firebase app.

```
firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
```

I am using the Firebase Admin SDK to interact with Firebase storage and Firestore from a service account, but the SDK does not have any methods to interact with the Firebase API.

Is there any way to get a token for a service account using the Firebase Admin SDK? Or is there any `firebaseAdmin.auth()` workaround where I could also allow requests from service accounts?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  Are you saying that you want to use Firebase Authentication to verify a token for a service account?  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to get a token for my service account. Or otherwise be able to authenticate a service account from the API

Comment: You can't use a service account to perform user-based auth with Firebase Authentication.  Firebase Auth is for end users.  You can use a service account to initialize a server SDK such as the Firebase Admin SDK, at which point it has permission to do anything with the products in your project.  It would help be define exactly what your end goal is here, other than to just "authenticate".

Comment: I have a Firebase API with an endpoint which is called by signed in users. This endpoint includes an authorization check using the `verifyIdToken()` method above. I now need to call that API endpoint with a separate application using a service account and the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: As I said, you can't do that.  Firebase Auth is for identifying end users.  Service accounts are for backend code to gain access to resources in your project.  A service account will never yield you an ID token that you can use with Firebase Auth.  You could set up your own authentication provider to mint a new Auth token on behalf of a service account, but you're looking at a lot of work there.

Comment: Resources excluding Firebase functions, of course